# Would a square waveform (or trapezoidal waveform) have frequency content lower than its fundamental frequency?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, buck, frequency-response, spectrum

I was trying to understand the LC circuit response for the circuit given below.
(Note: fsw indicates the frequency of input square wave as in a buck converter)

As far as I know, **for a linear circuit, only those frequency components which are present in the input can manifest at the output** ( Depending upon gain/attenuation of the filter circuit)

The last [snap](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1374896&seqNum=11) shows that **a square wave has frequency components which are multiples of fundamental freq** ( I dont know why dc component is not shown? )

For the circuit given below, **fundamental freq of input signal is 50kHz and resonant frequency of LC filter is 876Hz. I presume there is no frequnecy component present in input < 50kHz( other than dc).**

**Then why is the output having a  resonant frequency component?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because your input signal includes a DC step component that starts at t=0, in addition to the harmonics of the square wave. This step transient has excited the natural response of the LC circuit, and since there's no dissipative component, that response continues indefinitely.

Comment: I think Dave is right. However, there is an easy fix. Just add some small realistic amount of series resistance to your inductor and capacitor models. You can click on the components and add the series resistance. You don't necessarily have to put an actual resistor in the schematic.

Comment: So the rule,  "for a linear circuit, only those frequency components which are present in the input can manifest at the output" is applicable only for forced response. 

Natural response will exist on top of that. The nature of natural response doesn't depend upon exciting source.

Comment: Right. Also, for passive networks, the natural response will damp out over time.